# How do I jailbreak my iPad with Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, apple, ipad

I was recently given an Apple iPad and its software restrictions limit what I can do with it (installing software from other sources, customization, file explorer, etc). I know that the solution would be to "jailbreak" it, that is to say to gain root access on it.

How do I perform a jailbreak ? As most apps are created for other operating systems, I would appreciate a software recommendation.

I run Ubuntu 12.10 and own a first generation Apple iPad with iOS 5.1.1.

Comment: jail breaking isn't a topic for this site.

Comment: Thank you Web-E: I edited my question to make it more Ask Ubuntu relevant.

Comment: Ok but jailbreaking ipad illegal in some country (in US, but not iphone as far as I know) that is why I thought it should not be discussed over here.

Comment: Oh I never heard of that, I had to educate myself on your comment. Thus I edited my answer to note the following : gaining root access is legal at least in France (my country) and India (your country), so this doesn't make the question too localized nor does it promote illegal action.

Comment: @Web-E [Jailbreaking is NOT a crime](https://www.eff.org/pages/jailbreaking-not-crime-tell-copyright-office-free-your-devices), please stop spreading these silly ideas promoted by some corporations.

Comment: @TomBrossman the link you posted, doesn't tell it is declared right? It is a petition not a proof. Anyway I already mentioned [as far as I know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking#United_States). I don't know what is the latest rule. Anyway this isn't a place to argue on this topic.

Comment: There is not need to prove the right of ownership, it is plain to see. It is not possible to make criminal law preventing people from damaging their duly owned property. The only negative consequence for jail-braking/rooting a device is that any mfg warranty will be violated, and you could brick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To jailbreak your iPad, you need a special software on your Ubuntu computer and your USB cable. My advice is to use a program that worked for me, Absinthe.

- Download the correct version on [GreenPois0n](http://greenpois0n.com/downloads/) (don't be impressed by the name or the skull logo), depending on your iOS version. In your case of iOS 5.1.1, choose Absinthe 2.0.4. From personal experience, I know that you should not compulsorily choose the all newest version ; just stick with the version that was designed for your iOS version.
- Extract the archive you downloaded, launch the app called "absinthe". Choose "Run" if Ubuntu prompts you with a pop-up window.
- Follow the displayed instructions.

Good luck !

For more information about jailbreaking devices from Apple, see for instance [iDownload Blog](http://www.idownloadblog.com/jailbreak/). It should also be noted that the process of gaining root access on your device is legal in [most](http://www.01net.com/editorial/553850/jailbreaker-est-ce-legal-ou-pas/) [countries](http://cis-india.org/a2k/blog/analysis-copyright-amendment-bill-2012/tpm-copyright-amendment), but you'd better double check that for your own.

Comment: The download link is down.